# How to access JWT from laravel blade?

Tags: javascript, laravel, authentication, jwt

I'm using JWT (Json Web Token) auth in my Laravel 5.2 app. How can I get user_id from the token inside JavaScript  tags in my blade ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JWTAuth like Auth:

After you authenticate, get the user

```
$user = JWTAuth::user();
```

then pass data to view:

```
return view('posts', ['user' => $user]);
```

and you can use the data in blade:

```
{{ echo $user->id; }}
```